# SWI-Prolog: ERROR: Cannot find MinGW and/or MSYS

Tags: prolog, ffi, swi-prolog

I am attempting to install an appropriate package for matrix operations for Prolog using SWI-Prolog. For this, my eye fell on the [ffimatrix pack](http://swi-prolog.osuosl.org/pack/list?p=ffimatrix). In tried installing it using `pack_install(ffimatrix).`, but upon doing so it immediatly mentions it requires some dependencies (namely ffi). I then get the option to install these dependencies, which I do. Upon installing the [ffi pack](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=ffi) however, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Cannot find MinGW and/or MSYS.
```

I am not too familiar with Prolog, or what MinGW and MSYS are (or how to make use of them in Prolog), but how could I resolve this? I added a screenshot below with my whole attempt.

[image]